# How to specificy default ringtone for RingtonePreference with ringtoneType all

Tags: android-preferences

I'm trying to set have a RingtonePreference with ringtoneType all, but I'm trying to have the default sound be the default notification sound. Right now, it has the default as the default ringtone instead... how do I change that? (WhatsApp is able to do it so I know its possible)

Answer (score 0):

Ended up just making a subclass of RingtonePreference, overwriting the `onPrepareRingtonePickerIntent` method to always provide the default notification tone to `RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_DEFAULT_URI`, pretty minor change so hopefully its safe. Here's my class:

```
package com.myexample;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.RingtoneManager;
import android.preference.RingtonePreference;
import android.util.AttributeSet;

public class MyRingtonePreference extends RingtonePreference {
    public MyRingtonePreference(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    public MyRingtonePreference(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public MyRingtonePreference(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    protected void onPrepareRingtonePickerIntent(Intent ringtonePickerIntent) {

        ringtonePickerIntent.putExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_EXISTING_URI,
                onRestoreRingtone());

        ringtonePickerIntent.putExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_SHOW_DEFAULT, getShowDefault());
        if (getShowDefault()) {
            ringtonePickerIntent.putExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_DEFAULT_URI,
                    RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION));
        }

        ringtonePickerIntent.putExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_SHOW_SILENT, getShowSilent());
        ringtonePickerIntent.putExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_TYPE, getRingtoneType());
        ringtonePickerIntent.putExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_TITLE, getTitle());
    }
}
```